# I write an Java application which do some CRUD work, but it doesn't exit, why?

Tags: java, debugging

I write an Java application which connects to the DB and do some DB CRUD work, but the application always stop at the end of main and don't exit!

Do any one encountered similar problem and what tool do you use to debug this type of problem?

Comment: Yes I have. And I've used the default debugger of my IDE for that. But indeed, post some code please.

Comment: what tools are you using at the moment? are you using an IDE or writing in notepad? if so what ide? what database? what code? under what conditions is it failing? etc etc etc....

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change your settings?

I think you're  debugging with eclipse. With a wrong setting, eclipse stops at the end of the main, if an uncaught exception was thrown.

**Eclipse\Window\Preferences\Java\Debug\ - Suspend on uncaught exceptions**